# How to use pcl_ros with ROS 2 Eloquent?

Tags: ros, ros2, pcl, catkin, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I am trying to port a ROS 1 object tracking package (https://github.com/praveen-palanisamy/multiple-object-tracking-lidar) to ROS 2 Eloquent. The package I need to port depends on pcl_ros package (from perception_pcl repo: https://index.ros.org/p/pcl_ros/github-ros-perception-perception_pcl/#Eloquent). However, I have read from the documentation that it has CATKIN as build type and this makes me a bit confused about its usage. In particular, I want to build it from source to make it available as dependancy but I don't know how to deal with it to make it work with ROS 2. As far as I know, ROS 2 uses AMENT_CMAKE and not CATKIN. Is there a way to use it with ROS 2? If yes, could you describe me how?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
ROS 2 distro: Eloquent (from source)

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359821/how-to-use-pcl_ros-with-ros-2-eloquent?/) by [MaxCode](https://answers.ros.org/users/58049/maxcode/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pcl_ros has not been fully ported to ROS 2 yet. Onlt pcl_concersions have been completed. If you have need for pcl_ros, I could always use the help in helping porting it!

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MaxCode](https://answers.ros.org/users/58049/maxcode/) on 2020-08-19**:
Thank you very much for your answer. Now I analyze the situation to find a solution that suites my needs

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-08-19**:
Can you mark the answer as correct then?

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2022-02-24**:
Is there a way to see where the porting process is at now? Thanks